# Simple soap call return fatal error, function not a valid method

Tags: php, soap

I can't seem to wrap my head around SOAP calls. I've been trying for hours to get some simple information back from a WSDL file

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl');
$params = array(2017,1,'en');
$functions = $client->__soapCall(getMonthlyAverageExchangeRatesResponse, array(getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates, $params));
var_dump($functions);
```

but this only returns "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getMonthlyAverageExchangeRatesResponse") is not a valid method for this service..."

Doing a var dump of the functions

```
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
var_dump($functions);
```

shows me

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(104) "getInterestAndExchangeNamesResponse getInterestAndExchangeNames(getInterestAndExchangeNames $parameters)" [1]=> string(113) "getMonthlyAverageExchangeRatesResponse getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates(getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates $parameters)" [2]=> string(122) "getLatestInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse getLatestInterestAndExchangeRates(getLatestInterestAndExchangeRates $parameters)" [3]=> string(119) "getInterestAndExchangeGroupNamesResponse getInterestAndExchangeGroupNames(getInterestAndExchangeGroupNames $parameters)" [4]=> string(62) "getCrossRatesResponse getCrossRates(getCrossRates $parameters)" [5]=> string(71) "getAllCrossNamesResponse getAllCrossNames(getAllCrossNames $parameters)" [6]=> string(68) "getCalendarDaysResponse getCalendarDays(getCalendarDays $parameters)" [7]=> string(110) "getAnnualAverageExchangeRatesResponse getAnnualAverageExchangeRates(getAnnualAverageExchangeRates $parameters)" [8]=> string(104) "getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse getInterestAndExchangeRates(getInterestAndExchangeRates $parameters)" }
```

All I'm trying to do is to get the "getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates(getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates $parameters)".
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, took some trial and error, but I finally got the syntax. For anyone else struggling with similar simple SOAP requests that don't require any authentication-

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl');
$parameters = array(
'year' => 2017,
'month' => 1,
'languageid' => 'en'    
);
$functions =  $client->getMonthlyAverageExchangeRates($parameters);
```

If you want to take a look at the syntax given to understand how to use it in PHP

http://www.riksbank.se/sv/Rantor-och-valutakurser/Web-Services/